# Double Pointer being modified in an array mysteriously

Tags: c, string, malloc

Hello I have a function which populates a 2D array, consisting of words. I want to simply return the value of the pointer I entered the function with, but for some reason the pointer is now pointing to something else, strangely. I want to know how to fix this. Also wouldn't it be possible to do pointer arithmetic to fix this issue?(That's not what I want to do, I want to see what the issue is and fix it that way, but it'd be nice to know anyway). So it's supposed to be a 500 x 5 array, and even though I assign strings to 'dictPointer[i]', which I thought is supposed to represent "*dictPointer" and not "dictPointer", it seems as though I shouldn't have an issue. I need it to be this way because I wanted to print words starting from the initial pointer value. Also note that dictPointer is a pointer to pointer( **dictPointer)

```
char** readAndPopulateArray(FILE *f, char *fileName, char **dictPointer, int x ) { // x represents the number of words 
    // point is the word pointer
    int i = 0;
    char tempStr[80];
    char ch;
    f = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if ( f == NULL ) {
        printf("Cannot open %s. Verify it's in the right location\n", fileName);
    }

    while (fscanf(f, "%s", tempStr) == 1 ) {
        if( strlen(tempStr) == 4 ) {
            if(i == 0 ) {
                printf("Entering dictpointer points to %p\n", *dictPointer);
            }
            dictPointer[i] = tempStr;
                        if ( i == 499 ) {
                printf("Exiting dictPointer points to %p\n", *dictPointer);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    return dictPointer;
}
```

Below was how I called malloc for the matrix:

```
char** makeStringWordArray(int x, int letters ) { // x represents number of words, function stores one character each per word
    // letters represents number of letters in each word
    char *hold;
    int i, j = 0;
    char **dict = (char **)(malloc(x * sizeof(char*)) );
    for (i = 0; i<x; i++ ) {
            dict[i] = (char*)(malloc(letters*sizeof(char) + 1 ) );
        }

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear - on the 0-th iteration, you assign `dictPointer[0]`, which is the same as `*dictPointer`.  So of course it's going to change!

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm still not understanding how this all works. Isn't dictPointer always pointing to dictPointer[0] unless I explicitly change it? I mean that's what I want. Now if it was dictPointer[1] = 'string', how is that changing *dictPointer if it points at dictPointer[0]?

Comment: There is no 2D array. `char **` is not  2D array and cannot point to one. Why not use a 2D array? Oh, and don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general.

Comment: Because the assignment requires me to use dynamically allocated arrays, and which line are you referring to? And why not?

Comment: Ok, that all makes sense. Thank you very much, and wow I can't believe that there are books ought there teaching us garbage; that's crazy.

Comment: @M.M I'm not seeing the phrase "allocating an array" in [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) (though it is, admittedly, a draft, and not the final standard). What I _am_ seeing is "*The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.*" ([here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.4p2)). WRT static arrays -- Yes, let's drown the new programmer in technicalities. :P (In all seriousness, yes, you're correct, but I intentionally didn't mention the edge cases, to keep things simpler, and because I ran out of space)

Comment: @Shinji-san You can as well alocate a multidimensionan array. `malloc` just r3eturns the pointer to the first element. For a 2D array, an element of that array would be a 1D array.

Comment: Sorry about the typos!

Comment: @M.M Whoops, missed that phrase. (I'm assuming you're referring to "*used to access such an object or an array of such objects*", about a third of the way into 7.22.3.1?) Either way, there were bigger problems with my original comment (mixing extremely common implementation and the standard, without making clear which is which), so I've deleted it. I got thrown off by the lack of an actual definition for "array", and the only place I'd seen it used before was in the context of `int foo[12];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign every `dictPointer[i]` to the same pointer `tempStr`.  Then the lifetime of `tempStr` ends at the end of `readAndPopulateArray`, making `dictPointer[i]` invalid.

Perhaps you meant

```
strcpy(dictPointer[i], tempStr);
```

Comment: Sorry I still don't quite get it. tempStr changes everytime and so does i. It's not like it dictPointer[0] = tempStr for each iteration. So are you saying that each dictPointer[i] points to dictPointer[499] when the loop ends, or something else?

Comment: When the loop ends, `dictPointer` is an array of 500 copies of `&tempStr[0]`.  When the function ends, it's an array of 500 invalid pointers.

Comment: OHHH now I understand, thank you.